# Vim - LaTeX-Suite producing strange <++> symbol upon closing brackets with no content

Tags: vim, latex, macvim, latex-suite

Whenever I close anything in LaTeX-Suite (in MacVim), from `{}` to to `()` to `$$`, with no content inside, a strange symbol `<++>` is produced on the right about which I have no idea what is for. It doesn't seem to serve any distinguishable meaning. For example `section{abc}<++>` will just produce a literal `<++>` after the section in the output document. I'm not sure whether it's a bug, a behavior caused by some other settings/plugins(I'm not seeing similar things happening under other syntaxes though), or some intended behavior. This is greatly hindering my efficiency...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like that `<++>` is part of its templating system. Please report this issue to the project itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature.

It's the placeholder/marker character. It's meant to be jumped to. IIRC it was with `<C-J>` -- with lh-brackets (*), it's `<C-J>` with vim, and `<m-del>` with gvim.

(*) vim-latex bracketing system is remotely based upon the one from lh-brackets, except the latter has continued to evolve.

Comment: Thanks. I also thought it could be something in a similar vein to TextMate snippet but couldn't find a key to jump to it. There should be documentation for such features?

Comment: Normally it's indeed documented. As I haven't use vim-latex for a long time, I don't remember exactly what to search. You'll have to browse the documentation from `:h vim-latex` I guess.