# Unwanted text appears every time I close a bracket in VIM using VimTex

Tags: vim, latex, vim-plugin

I am typesetting a latex file in VIM using the [Vimtex plugin](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex).

Every time I close a bracket, this text shows up automatically in the `<++>`.
For example:

```
\section{This is one}<++>

\section{The variable $V_L$<++> explains things}<++>

\begin{equation}
    <+content+>
    \label{<+label+>}
\end{equation}<++>
```

LaTeX compiles my text with those printed out in the pdf so I have to manually remove the every time. This behavior goes from `$$` to `{}` to others also and even inside certain areas when using autocompletion features wit `F5`.

I did look add [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29139463/vim-latex-suite-producing-strange-symbol-upon-closing-brackets-with-no-co) but it did not provide much help as to **how** to solve my issue.

- How can I prevent the from being added to my tex files?
- If they are a feature meant for something I do not understand, how do I prevent them from compiling in my pdf's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of the documentation on [the vim-latex (not Vimtex) repo on github](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/blob/master/doc/latex-suite.txt)
explains how the macro system works, how it's useful and solely meant for editing

```
NOTE: Place Holders
    -------------
    Almost all macros provided in Latex-Suite implement Stephen Riem's
    bracketing system and Gergely Kontra's JumpFunc() for handling
    place-holders. This consists of using "place-holders" to mark off
    locations where the next relevant editing has to be done. As an example,
    when you type EFI in |insert-mode|, you will get the following:  >
        \begin{figure}[<+htpb+>]
            \centering
            \includegraphics{<+file+>}
            \caption{<+caption text+>}
            \label{fig:<+label+>}
        \end{figure}<++>
    The text <+htpb+> will be selected and you will be left in |select-mode|
    so that you can continue typing straight away. After having typed in the
    placement specifier, you can press <Ctrl-J> (while still in insert-mode).
    This will take you directly to the next "place-holder". i.e, <+file+> will
    be visually selected with Vim in select mode again for typing in the file
    aaaa. This saves on a lot of key presses.
```

**Note:** Upon testing I realized that the placeholder only appears when the bracketing is empty.