# What are those weird tags "<++>" in vim good for?

Tags: vim

i am quite new to vim, but always when i close a bracket, the editor inserts those mysterious "<++>" characters. A friend told me, that those are for navigation, but i don't know how to jump between them and now i have to get rid of them always. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29139463/vim-latex-suite-producing-strange-symbol-upon-closing-brackets-with-no-co if vim-latex is confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

You've either installed vim-latex, or my [lh-brackets plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets). As I have very few users, and quite unlikely newcomers, I'll bet on vim-latex. Moreover my plugin uses `<++>` only with (La)TeX documents, and it uses `«»` elsewhere.

They are placeholders to jump to (back and forth). With vim-latex, they are bound to `CTRL+J` by default IIRC. With my plugins, it's the same default with vim, but `ALT+DEL` with gvim. My lh-brackets plugin also has `ALT+END` (with gvim) to close and jump over all the next closing-brackets.

In both case, it's possible to remove the explicit markers. It's documented. `:h vim-latex` (I guess), or `:h g:use_place_holders` (w/ lh-brackets)